# open() does it load a file onto the ram?

Tags: linux, file

In Linux when I call open() on a file, is the complete data loaded on the ram?

I am asking this because the file i need to open is a huge file(around 700MB). Such a large file, if it is getting loaded, it might create a problem for other applications and making the system slower.

If complete data is not loaded(because on demand paging or similar things), then what can we assume to be the initial size that is loaded?

Just if it matters, here are my file details.

File type : Binary

File Size : varies in between 700MB - 2GB

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. It just gives file a descriptor called [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) which then you can use to do read / write and some other operations. Think file descriptor as an abstraction or an handle over what lays on disk.

You should also read manual page for [open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open). It states

> The open() function shall establish the connection between a file and
>   a file descriptor. It shall create an open file description that
>   refers to a file and a file descriptor that refers to that open file
>   description.

Answer (score 0):

> In Linux when I call open() on a file, is the complete data loaded on the ram?

No.

> what can we assume to be the initial size that is loaded?

Zero.

Comment: Thank you. So when is it loaded? If i read 10 bytes from an offset of say 20, is it that only 10 bytes is loaded?

Comment: It isn't defined, and there are various levels involved. The OS itself probably only loads one block, but the driver and disk controller and the disk itself between them may load an entire cluster, and any of those elements may also initiate a read-ahead if they think you're accessing sequentially.